# How to scrollable position in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi I have a **listview** with 11 elements. sometimes I want the user can **scoll upto** maximum 9th element and sometimes i want to **scroll upto** 5th element. So can we set maximum scroll position in listview depending on condition?

Thanks
Sunil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create an `OnTouchListener` and attach it to your `ListView`. In the `onTouch` event, check whether the maximum position has been exceeded, and call `scrollTo` to prevent the scroll from going past the maximum.

Alternatively, you could simply modify your `ListAdapter` to sometimes only list 9 or 5 elements when you want to limit the scroll.